# How to make the server acknowledge a browsers state when set asynchronously

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please bear with me, I need help.

On my site:

1. **index.php** - displays 20 links in this form:

   ```
   $result = mysql_query("my query");

   while($slice = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $url = $slice['url'];
        $perf  = $slice['perf']; 

        <a class="ajaxquery" data-title="<? echo $perf; ?>" href="$<? echo $url ?>">anchor</a>

   endwhile;
   ```
2. If someone clicks on one of the 20 links, I have this ajax code, which see's which `$perf` is clicked, sending the data to `session.php`:

   ```
   function ajaxsession(){
       $("a.ajaxquery").click(function() {
           var perf = $(this).data('title');
           $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "/session.php", data: "perf="+perf, success: function(html){ $("#results").append(html); } });
       });
   }
   ```
3. This code sends the following to `session.php`:

   ```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['perf'] = $_POST['perf']; // Store session data
   ```
4. And on my `single.php` page I call the variable stored in the session:

   ```
   echo $_SESSION['perf'];
   ```

On `single.php` I get the right `$perf` as long as I get back to `index.php` *using the home link*.

If I get back to `index.php` using the browsers *back arrow*, then the `$perf` is not updated using the `onclick` jQuery code.

Do you have any ideas on why is this happening? I am thinking that maybe I should destroy the session somehow once it reaches `single.php`. Is that a good idea?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question, in that the back button is not party to your click handler. Have you considered either `COOKIE`s or `SESSION`s? Or some other way to store a current state on the client for the server to use without roundtrip?

Comment: I am just a newb :( and I can't seem to make this work

Comment: Suggestion (unrelated to your problem): Replace `data: "perf="+perf` with `data: {perf: perf}` or *you* will have to ensure the value is properly url-encoded (which you want to avoid - especially when it's that easy).

Comment: Hint, before you do anything with the `perf` value asynchronously, set it to a `COOKIE` or `SESSION` value and then use that value. Then, if the `POST` value is not available, check the `COOKIE`/`SESSION` value next, THEN default to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'back button' will usually return to and load a cached copy of the page. If you need to have that "previous" page automatically reload when the user goes "back" to it, you'll have to send out that page with no-cache headers when it's first loaded.